# Error: the account XXXXXXXXXX does not exist

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have already run my hyperledger fabric network. So I have already registered, enrolled and put into couchdb wallet my users. Now I try to evaluate transaction 'ClientAccountBalance'. My node.js app:

```
let configPATH = 'path/to/config.yaml';

async function networkConnectorForUser(email) {
    let wallet = await Wallets.newCouchDBWallet("http://XXXXX@XXXXX:5984");
    let user = await wallet.get(email);

    // connection profile
    let connectionProfile = yaml.safeLoad(readFileSync(configPATH, 'utf-8'));

    // create new gateway
    let gateway = new Gateway();
    await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, {
        wallet,
        identity: user
    });

    // get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to
    let network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');
    return network;
}


async function transferTx(senderEmail, recipientEmail) {
    let networkForSender = await networkConnectorForUser(senderEmail);
    let networkForRecipient = await networkConnectorForUser(recipientEmail);

    // get recipient id
    let contractForRecipient = networkForRecipient.getContract('token-erc-20');
    let recipientID = await contractForRecipient.evaluateTransaction('ClientAccountID');
    console.log(`recipientID for ${recipientEmail}: `, recipientID.toString('ascii'));

    // get total supply sender before transfer
    let contractForSender = networkForSender.getContract('token-erc-20');
    let totalSupplySender = await contractForSender.evaluateTransaction('TotalSupply');
    console.log(`totalSupply for sender ${senderEmail} before transfer: `, totalSupplySender.toString('ascii'));

    // get total supply recipient before transfer
    let totalSupplyRecipient = await contractForRecipient.evaluateTransaction('TotalSupply');
    console.log(`totalSupply for recipient ${recipientEmail} before transfer: `, totalSupplyRecipient.toString('ascii'));

    let recipientBalance = await contractForRecipient.evaluateTransaction('ClientAccountBalance');
    console.log('tokenName: ', tokenName.toString('ascii'));
 
}

transferTx('address.ru', 'address2.ru');
```

I receive next output:

```
recipientID for address2.ru:  XXXXXXX
totalSupply for sender address.ru before transfer:  1000
totalSupply for recipient address2.ru before transfer:  1000
path/to/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/query/singlequeryhandler.js:60
                    const responseError = Object.assign(new Error('peer error response: ' + result.message), result);
                                                        ^

Error: the account XXXXXXX does not exist
    at SingleQueryHandler.evaluate (/path/to/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/query/singlequeryhandler.js:60:57)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Transaction.evaluate (/path/to/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:319:25)
    at async transferTx (/path/to/test-fabric-example/transfer.js:489:21) {
  isEndorsed: false,
  payload: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
  status: 500
}
```